# Mat Paginator not working in Angular Material Table

Tags: angular, angular-material

I am developing a sample code to use pagination . For this , i am using Angular Material Table . I have managed to show the data inside the table as well as the controls for pagination , but somehow it is not working as it should be.

**Below is the stackblitz repo link :**

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-i4lmdx?file=src/Service/app.service.ts

**Important :** It is showing the following error on my VSCode.

[image: Error in Code]

[image: Error in Terminal]

**Any solution please ?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a lot of mistakes in the stackblitz you linked, to name a few:

- No imports for the angular material components you are using
- Not calling the correct component
- Not specifying the correct data source in the mat-table

the error you are seeing

> Property 'paginator' does not exist on type 'any[]'.

happens because you are trying to assign an object (paginator) into an array (dummyDataArray), you should instead be setting the paginator on the `MatTableDataSource` object (in your case - `dataSource`)

Here is a working [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/mat-table-with-paginator-almost-working?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts)

Comment: Moshezauros : Thank you brother....your solution worked for me ...thank you once again..... Have a great day .... :)